# How to solve duplicated rows in the JPQL query with many-to-one?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, distinct, jpql

My query almost works but it returns duplicate rows, because the team name is duplicated. How can I solve this problem?

I have : `"team glass"`, `"team foot"`, and `"team swim"`.
`TeamUserCompany` has a many-to-one relationship to `Team`.
When I query for team names containing `"team"` I get duplicated rows because it contains `"team glass"`, `"team foot"`, and `"team swim"`!

[image]

In the front end I need to show companies!

```java
@Query("SELECT distinct teamUserComp FROM TeamUserCompany teamUserComp WHERE teamUserComp.team.name like %?1% ");
```

Entity

```java
public class TeamUserCompany extends AbstractEntity {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Company company;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    private Team team;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any join in your code.

Comment: Sorry for my English, my question wasn't clear, but you can read de description please.

Comment: If what you need is a query, then post sample data of your table(s) and your expected results.

Comment: I add a screen to explain my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a Group by it solved the problem.

```
@Query("SELECT distinct teamUserComp FROM TeamUserCompany teamUserComp WHERE teamUserComp.team.name like %?1% group by (teamUserInter.company)");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want distinct companies you have to select distinct companies and not distinct `TeamUserCompany`:

```sql
SELECT distinct c 
FROM TeamUserCompany tuc 
JOIN tuc.company c
WHERE tuc.team.name like %?1%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jens, but doesn't works, it return an empty result.